# Writing a Python method to reference the Class attribute in the derived class, rather than base class

Tags: class, python-3.x, polymorphism

As someone who worked more in Java, I am having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around polymorphic references to class attributes in Python.

What I would like to do is have a method in the base class which modifies a "static" variable (aka class attribute) of the base class, but when calling the method from the derived class, for the method to modify the class attribute of the derived class, not the base class. Note, I am NOT overriding the method in the derived class.

For example, I have something like:

```
class BaseClass:
    itemList = []

    def addItem(thing):
        BaseClass.itemList.append(thing)

class Child1(BaseClass):
    pass

class Child2(BaseClass):
    pass

...

Child1.addItem("foo")

Child2.addItem("bar")

print(str(Child1.itemList))
```

I'd like: "foo"

I get: "foo, bar"

Now, I understand that because of "BaseClass.itemList.append(thing)", it will reference the class attribute of the base class.

Put another way, is there a way to avoid saying "BaseClass.itemList", but keep it static, or do I need to instead override the method in each of the child classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a "static" class variable that can be changed by every instance of the class:

```
class BaseClass:
    itemList = []    
    def addItem(self, thing):
        self.itemList.append(thing)


class Child1(BaseClass):
    itemList = []       


class Child2(BaseClass):
    itemList = []       

# each class has its own "itemList"
# now we can instantiate each class and use the different itemLists:

c1 = Child1()
c1.addItem("foo")

c2 = Child2()
c2.addItem("bar")

c3 = Child1()
c3.addItem("foo2")

print(str(Child1.itemList)) # prints: ['foo', 'foo2']
print(str(Child2.itemList)) # prints: ['bar']
```

Comment: Thanks alfasin, tried out what you wrote, it does what I want, though I did not expect that syntax. 

Looks like I have to instantiate the children to use the method, even though it modifies the class variable. Also, for some reason I though local instances of itemList would be created automatically in the derived classes, but playing around with it shows it does not. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorLegros While in Java and other strongly typed languages we create "static classes" (Singletons). In python we use [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).